# Geoserver WFS fetch CORS not working

Tags: openlayers, fetch-api

I am trying to do a wfs request to an external geoserver. Setting `mode: no-cors` works but I want to parse the result directly which is then not possbile..

```
fetch(this.selectedLayer.url + '/wfs', {
  method: 'POST',
  Origin: 'anonymous',
  body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(this.wfs)
})
```

How to tell the geoserver that my application is just `annonymus` as it works in the WMSSources like this:

```
source: new TileWMS({
  url: "https://maps.xyz/service",
  params: {LAYERS: "l1,l2"},
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
}),
```

Can't seem to find the correct header I have to pass in fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no feasible way to circumvent this issue. In the end you will need a proxy at some point so just get one straight away and the problem is solved. Could have saved me a lot of time to directly use the proxy instead.